# Daylight savings not applied in qml in windows exe compiled with mingw-w64

Tags: qt, qml, mingw, cross-compiling

Ok, this might be a very specific problem, but I wasn't able to find any solution in several weeks of on and off trying to solve this.

I have a gitlab CI which is compiles windows executables with this docker image: https://github.com/mdimura/docker-mingw-qt5 (Arch linux mingw-w64 with qt5)

In my qml file there is following code:

```
var testTime = new Date
console.info("normal Date: " + testTime.toString())
console.info("Date.getHours: " + testTime.getHours())
console.info("Date.getUTCHours: " + testTime.getUTCHours())
console.info("Date.getTimezoneOffset: " + testTime.getTimezoneOffset())
```

when I compile and run it on my local machine I get the expected output, for example:

```
Info: normal Date: Fr Apr 20 14:55:23 2018 GMT+0200
Info: Date.getHours: 14
Info: Date.getUTCHours: 12
Info: Date.getTimezoneOffset: -120
```

when I get the executable compiled by mingw I get following output:

```
Info: normal Date: Fr Apr 20 14:50:39 2018 GMT+0100
Info: Date.getHours: 13
Info: Date.getUTCHours: 12
Info: Date.getTimezoneOffset: -60
```

Notice that the time given by `testTime.toString()` is correct in both cases (except the timezone), but the timezone offset and the value given by `testTime.getHours()` is off by one hour.

When I set the time settings in windows to not use daylight savings both executables return the same, correct values.

To check that this is really qml's or javascript's fault I also added

```
qInfo() << "Qt time hour: " << QTime::currentTime().hour();
```

to my main.cpp. This also prints the correct time in all cases.

I even compiled the Qt packages in the docker myself, still the same problem. Does anyone have an idea what is going on here and how I could fix it?

Comment: Maybe you need a special file for your mingw docker image to tell it what your timezone is...

Comment: @mike510a The docker image shouldn't need to know what my timezone is as the executable should work in all time zones. And the timezone definitions and data should be in the c library, shouldn't it?

Comment: not necessarily. on Linux the time zone is defined by using an environment variable `TZ='America/New_York'; export TZ`   so its quite possible that all you have to do is define the time zone that way or by modifying a file in the `/etc/` folder of the docker image if there is one

Comment: @mike510a unfortunately that doesn't seem to help. I created the symbolic link /etc/localtime to my timezone in the docker image and rebuild. The errors are still there.

Comment: did you try setting the TZ='' environment variable?

Comment: I was able to test the same program with another version of mingw using MXE. As the executable compiled with that works just fine I now suspect a bug in the Arch packages used in the original docker. I will file a bug report with them later.

Answer (score 1):

In case somebody find this later - the problem is now tracked as an [issue on my PKGBUILDs repository](https://github.com/Martchus/PKGBUILDs/issues/67).

Let's see whether I can find an answer to question if @Jay Tea provides more information.

Answer (score 0):

set the TZ environment variable before you run the exe

```
export TZ=CET-1CEST

./yourExecutable.exe
```

Comment: Unfortunately still no luck. I used `set TZ=CET-1CEST; .\MyExe.exe` on my windows, but it still gives me the same behavior as before.

Comment: well, the point is to have a working executable on windows though. I don't see how that is going to help me. Defining TZ like that in the docker before building also doesn't seem to help.